# How to fix code not moving channel under category

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

The code created category and channel and gave me this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined` without moving the channel in the category
This is the code to the error:

```js
    const guild = message.guild;
    const channel = await guild.channels.create(`ticket: ${message.author.tag}`);
    let category = guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name == "Tickets" && c.type == "category")
    if (!category) {
   type: 'category',
   })
  .catch(console.error);
    }


    channel.setParent(category);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `channel.setParent` call fails on [this](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/e848d25c86fcd4a11a7879f7dcd55d0bc93faa6d/src/structures/GuildChannel.js#L420) line since `category` is `undefined`. Looks like the guild does not have a category channel named `'Tickets'`.

Since you're creating the channel if it doesn't exist, you should `await` it and reassign `category` to the newly created channel to use in the `channel.setParent` call.

```js
if (!category) {
  category = await server.channels.create('Tickets', {
    type: 'category',
    // ...
  })
}

channel.setParent(category)
```

Btw, it looks like `updateOverwrite` is not a valid option in the [`server.channels.create`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create) call. I think it should be `permissionOverwrites`. Check the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create).

---

This is unrelated to the question but I would recommend renaming `category` to `categoryChannel` for clarity.

Comment: Additionally, I think what actually causes this issue is, that `channel` is not available to that scope, but it's hard to tell, since @Newbie did not post a formatted text version of his code

Comment: @Keimeno `channel` is indeed in scope. The issue is that `category` is `undefined`. Do let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan Yes, you are right I only made it to create category if there is no category, but forgot to define it again.

Comment: @Newbie No worries. The next time you post a question, please add the code and the stack trace as text and not as images.

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan Yes, I am sorry, I will actually edit the question with code right now.

Comment: @Newbie Thanks. Btw, it looks like `updateOverwrite` is not a valid option in the [`create`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create) call.

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan Actually, it is for the channel or whatever, but redefining it  in the if statement worked thanks!

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan You can see more about it [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/search?q=updateOverwrite).

Comment: If you check the docs, you'll see `updateOverwrite` is not a valid option. Btw, the code inside the `if` block is not right - `server.channels.create` is missing.

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan updateOverwrite is all about the permissions..

Comment: @Newbie I'm guessing it should be `permissionOverwrites`. Check the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create).

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan I don't know, but it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan Look at the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=updateOverwrite).

Comment: @Newbie I meant that `updateOverwrite` is not a valid option in the `server.channels.create` call. If you check the docs on the [`GuildChannelManager#create`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create)method, you'll see `updateOverwrite` is not present in the options list.

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan You are right, It doesn't change the permissions for the category, I am sorry!

Comment: @Newbie No worries.

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan I fixed it, I was getting ahead of myself, I am really sorry again! Thanks!

Comment: @Newbie I'm glad you fixed it.